# SecurityException MVC3 Request Failed Permissions

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

If you navigate to this [link](http://www.nightingalecross.co.uk) you'll find that your hit with a securityexception.

> Server Error in '/' Application. Security Exception Description: The application attempted to perform an operation not allowed by the
>   security policy.  To grant this application the required permission
>   please contact your system administrator or change the application's
>   trust level in the configuration file.
>
> Exception Details: System.Security.SecurityException: Request failed.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [SecurityException: Request failed.]
>   System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.ThrowSecurityException(RuntimeAssembly
>   asm, PermissionSet granted, PermissionSet refused,
>   RuntimeMethodHandleInternal rmh, SecurityAction action, Object demand,
>   IPermission permThatFailed) +168
>   System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.ThrowSecurityException(Object
>   assemblyOrString, PermissionSet granted, PermissionSet refused,
>   RuntimeMethodHandleInternal rmh, SecurityAction action, Object demand,
>   IPermission permThatFailed) +100
>   System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.CheckSetHelper(PermissionSet
>   grants, PermissionSet refused, PermissionSet demands,
>   RuntimeMethodHandleInternal rmh, Object assemblyOrString,
>   SecurityAction action, Boolean throwException) +278
>   System.Security.PermissionSetTriple.CheckSetDemand(PermissionSet
>   demandSet, PermissionSet& alteredDemandset,
>   RuntimeMethodHandleInternal rmh) +69
>   System.Security.PermissionListSet.CheckSetDemand(PermissionSet pset,
>   RuntimeMethodHandleInternal rmh) +156
>   System.Security.PermissionListSet.DemandFlagsOrGrantSet(Int32 flags,
>   PermissionSet grantSet) +33
>   System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.ReflectionTargetDemandHelper(Int32
>   permission, PermissionSet targetGrant, CompressedStack
>   securityContext) +128
>   System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.ReflectionTargetDemandHelper(Int32
>   permission, PermissionSet targetGrant) +54
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319;
>   ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.272

Strangely enough you are only presented this error once!

Is it something to do with my code?

Answer (score 1):

Does the code the site running on in your control?

I guess there is some startup code (maybe in global.asax.cs) that attempts to access a protected resource, maybe a folder/file, and fails. And that code only runs once, when the application starts.

Comment: why would it run on every page that access the database though?

Comment: it has all the dlls required to run, would ninject be a problem? because it isn't in the bin folder....

Comment: Not in every page, just first time (at least that's what you've mentioned in your question).

Comment: Try disabling code that runs in global.asax startup methods and see if that makes a change.

Comment: No its once on every page that access the database sorry, not just once when the site runs.

Comment: You must inspect your code to see what things only run the first time in every page. Sorry, this is not the kind of specific question to ask here. You must find it yourself / with the help of Google.